# Intel AC7260 wifi card disconnects and have to restart

Tags: wireless, dell, 15.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have a Dell XPS 9333 with Ubuntu 15.04 and Intel wifi card (ac7260). The wifi-ac connection is slow and it disconnects after couple of minutes (it varies). After the disconnect I have to reboot in order to reconnect.

I have the latest firmware for the kernel: driverversion=3.19.0-18-generic firmware=25.17.12.0

Does anyone has any solution for linux and intel cards?

*I have also an external usb wifi from Edimax that doesn't have any issues - so only the laptop intel card has this issue.

`radu@radu-XPS13-9333:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 6b
       serial: 5c:51:4f:7c:93:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-18-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:f0400000-f0401fff
radu@radu-XPS13-9333:~$ lspci -nn
...
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)`

Comment: Is there any clue in the log? `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: after setting the region to my country code it's more stable (with sudo iw reg set XX). But nothing helpful with dmesg. only: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

Comment: I've found a bug report too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1354975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read in the bug report you linked?

> Performance is related to the access point. With some access point the
>   laptop would not even connect, with other it will connect but not in a
>   stable way, while with others it will work with no problems.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:[CODE]sudo iw reg get[/CODE]If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Reboot and let us know the result.

Comment: I have set the reg set but is goes to DE. There are the same rules for my country(RO) and DE.. The connection is more stable since I set the reg code. About my AP: it's an Asus RT-AC68U. I'm on AC mode (5Ghz, AES enc, 80 MHz bandwitdth)

Comment: but it still disconnects (and I have to reboot). AP setting: 1. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16678835/2015-06-10%2008.01.23.png     2. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16678835/2015-06-10%2007.59.30.png

Comment: BTW, I would vote up your answer, but not enough rep points; so I will say thank you for your help here

Comment: Instead of 'N/AC mixed', I'd suggest B/G/N/AC mixed. Likewise, I would experiment with channel widths of 80 or 40 or 20 Mhz. You connection may be a bit slower but stable. Lightning-fast speeds are no good if you can't actually stay connected.