# T450s on 15.10 Kernel 4.2.6 iwlwifi 7265 association step timeout

Tags: intel-wireless

I am setting up a new T450s with Intel AC 7265D wifi card. Windows 7 wif works perfectly. So, should not be a HW problem. But dual boot to 14.04 wifi didn't work after applying all kinds of work around found in this forum. I then upgraded to 15.10 with kernel upgrade to 4.2.6, applied latest firmware 15.227938.0 (it uses iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode, the latest I could find) following chili555's step-by-step instruction. Still no wifi. Behavior is endless wifi authentication request. From dmesg output below, it seems that authentication is complete, but association with the router keeps failing. I wonder why they don't like each other. and what is preventing them from being associated...Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

```
=====================================
dmesg |grep wlan0
[    5.902703] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    5.984403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.292143] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   33.086486] wlan0: authenticate with <router mac addr>
[   33.092328] wlan0: send auth to <router mac addr> (try 1/3)
[   33.180050] wlan0: authenticated
[   33.180218] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   33.180222] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   33.184143] wlan0: associate with <router mac addr> (try 1/3)
[   33.288048] wlan0: associate with <router mac addr> (try 2/3)
[   33.392015] wlan0: associate with <router mac addr> (try 3/3)
[   33.495959] wlan0: association with <router mac addr> timed out
.....

lshw -c network===============
-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 59
       serial: <mac addr>
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.6-040206-generic firmware=15.227938.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:e1000000-e1001fff

lspci -nnk===========
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
=====================================
```

Comment: Please add: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e DFS` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Did you implement these steps? http://askubuntu.com/questions/633307/intel-ac7260-wifi-card-disconnects-and-have-to-restart/633957#633957

Comment: Hi chili555, yes I did go through this particular thread. Changing router setting to WPA2-AES didn't help. After the test, I fell it back to the original setting which is a combined mode WPA-PSK [TKIP] + WPA2-PSK [AES] (afraid it might impact my other device connections). It is an old netgear WT624 v3 wifi router with automatic 108M on channel 6 with US region setting. IPv6 was set to ignore; I just review this thread again and set regdomain=US; reboot, no improvement. $ dmesg |grep wlan0
[    6.113363] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: $ dmesg | grep -e iwl -e DFS
[    5.111778] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.227938.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.136131] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    5.137370] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.137806] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.232012] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.300413] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1230.816492] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP

Comment: The driver `iwlwifi` doesn't like TKIP. Also, as you can see, the region is not US: " DFS Master region: unset"

Comment: I removed the TKIP and rebooted router, no improvement yet. sudo iw reg set US and gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda set REGDOMAIN=US; DFS Master Region still shows unset...did I miss some steps to change DFS?

Comment: You might try a reboot and then check: `dmesg | grep domain` We hope we see: `cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US`

Comment: Done that, grep domain shows "updated" but grep -e DFS still shows unset.. need to run into a meeting... will continue later this afternoon...thanks for your help...I am sure you will help me get to the end point

Comment: $ dmesg |grep domain
...
[    5.298324] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
But it is not like what we hoped to see (no "US" shown); when I check DFS region, it is still showing "unset"

Comment: Please check: `cat /etc/default/crda` Just show us the final line.

Comment: final line shows 
REGDOMAIN= US (before there was no space in front of "US", then I added a space, still the same result.)

Comment: There should be no space. Then try: `sudo iw reg set US` and verify that it sticks: `sudo iw reg get` Note and post any errors or warnings.

Comment: Removed space. no error on set US, but it doesn't seem to stick:     sudo iw reg get
country 00: DFS-UNSET
 (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
 (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
 (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
 (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
 (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall crda wireless-regdb` and then: `sudo apt-get install wireless-crda` Reboot and check: `sudo iw reg get`

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall crda wireless-regdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/68.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
ng to unpack .../wireless-regdb_2014.11.18-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking wireless-regdb (2014.11.18-1ubuntu1) over (2014.11.18-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up wireless-regdb (2014.11.18-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up crda (3.13-1) ...

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall wireless-crda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,664 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 209364 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wireless-crda_1.16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wireless-crda (1.16) over (1.16) ...
Setting up wireless-crda (1.16) ...

Comment: $ sudo iw reg set US
jfan@james-PC:~$ sudo iw reg get
country 00: DFS-UNSET
 (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
 (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
 (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
 (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
 (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
 (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
Looks like re-install didn't help, getting the same results as before re-install after reboot

Comment: Hi chili555, shall I try to remove and reinstall crda again or you think it is better to work on the kernel level (maybe fall back to the old 4.2.0)? Thanks!

Comment: tried removal and re-install crda and regdb, same result. Used live USB boot back to 14.04, was able to set iw reg to US, it sticks. However, wlan0 associate behavior is exactly the same timeout as in 15.10. Shall I look somewhere else for root cause?

Comment: Have you tried the live DVD or USB for Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Yes. First tried USB boot for 15.10, it didn't stick the US setting. I then tried 14.04. Since it is USB boot, DFS setting won't register. iw reg get shows US. But association still fails in the same way.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` As we see in `dmesg`, N speeds are not available from your router.

Comment: I followed your command, is there a way to validate if the command stick? 11n is indeed disabled?

Comment: Please try: `cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable` It ought to return `1`. Is there any improvement in the ability to connect?

Comment: The return of this command show 1 as expected. I also followed another link on the forum to set the following line in iwlwifi.conf with "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1 (the only line in iwlwifi.conf. Reboot, association still fails the same way. no improvement

Comment: The file `iwlwifi.conf` should contain more than just that one line. The advice given in the other post is faulty. Please see: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13599878/

Comment: Here is my iwlwifi.conf file showing: cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi ieee80211_regdom="US"
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
did reboot. still no improvement

Comment: `options iwlwifi ieee80211_regdom="US"` is incorrect. Please remove.

Comment: removed.  cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1   did reboot... same result no wifi yet

Comment: Now I ran the wireless-info script, is there a way to upload it for more analysis? it is too big for a comment reply

Comment: Please post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: thanks chili555   pasted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/13902277/

Comment: I upgraded to 4.3 generic kernel and applied 7265-16 ucode firmware. still the same association time out. Is there a way to see what is exactly is failing?

Comment: May I see another wireless_script? http://paste.ubuntu.com Also, the logs may help us: `dmesg | grep iwl` and: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n20` As the result will be lengthy, paste it as well and give us the links.

Comment: new wireless-info script result pasted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/14282638/;  command output pasted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/14282758/

Answer (score 0):

We see this in your wireless script in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:

> options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
>   p2p_disabled=1

As you can see, *p2p_disabled* is not a valid parameter:

```
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
```

I suggest that you do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if connectivity is improved.

You might try installing more recent firmware:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware
sudo ./install
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: The reg domain was 00. Tried to set to US, but it didn't stick. crda domain file has only one line: REGDOMAIN=US. These steps were tried before on kernel 4.2.6 last month. when I used USB to boot 15.10, reg domain was set to US (sticked), it didn't help with the wifi at the time. I'll reboot now and let you know.

Comment: Did reboot, no improvement; not sure why it has this error: [    5.076352] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2; Is there a way to pre-disable HT and VHT? is  the ipv6 ignore setting to disable WMM/QoS feature of the wireless card?

Comment: The firmware error is to indicate that the driver looked for and failed to find the -17 firmware. It went on to find an earlier firmware and loaded it. A Google search doesn't even locate any -17 firmware file. It may be called for in the driver so it will load when issued a few months (years??) from now. HT/VHT is disabled already by *11n_disable=1*. Disabling IPv6 is to stop the driver/hardware looking for an IPv6 address when none is available from the router and/or your ISP. I will keep studying your logs.

Comment: thanks very much for your time. I found this bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96471. similar to mine. This caused me to put in the p2p disable options in (incorrectly). BTW, I also tried using iphone as AP, same behavior of failure to connect. This makes me think the issue is not on the AP. As both cases, it works when booted into windows7. It is somehow the association step got stuck.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: tried to install following your instruction above, reboot shows the same association timeout. Don't see an improvement.

Comment: The firmware from git is only up to 15. I checked lshw showing still the 16.242414.0 was used as before the install